# Plotly graph with same X and multiple Y axes with undefined number of data

Tags: python, plotly

I've developed a software that reads data from csv file and show data in a chart with multiple Y axes.
For each signal in my csv file I have a line in the chart and for each line in the chart there is an axes.

If the number of signals contained in csv file is unknown, so there are more than six for example (S1...S7,S8,S9,etc....), how can I auto generate Y axis for each signal??

Now my program is build like I know the number of signals in the csv file. I've already tried to create a `for` that modify the keyword `yaxis` but is not possible.

My csv file:

```
DateTime;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6
2020-07-17 09:57:27.119916;725.9926027110598;730.5730869210306;946.2937510737263;542.341137182406;758.5531610786929;512.2027881299339
2020-07-17 09:57:28.119916;761.1846087077208;984.1009029835216;974.8724733720549;576.8019892357476;751.6553704523698;855.5439493088621
2020-07-17 09:57:29.119916;618.7837289058051;823.9970681226491;594.2841714340789;873.3093170922189;770.0875733375253;681.1715820388949
2020-07-17 09:57:30.119916;515.9456035777555;533.017970929369;639.3409213385498;542.4405737836958;514.4985515824058;650.5229638670448
2020-07-17 09:57:31.119916;589.1350057317254;605.703259361724;602.3181712775759;860.9749699475683;801.7960812507487;562.400896160191
2020-07-17 09:57:32.119916;626.2528314431347;615.7078057434281;643.2023497200336;709.6997180536518;741.365852401098;712.4384053449293
2020-07-17 09:57:33.119916;553.9768845577024;961.7714859567449;519.8207498752649;551.8006708566627;511.7426656331682;849.3428394570542
2020-07-17 09:57:34.119916;994.8208541190293;700.59423301376;569.1853469890981;997.5842090634065;621.2070112896865;848.5079857917269
2020-07-17 09:57:35.119916;502.2301607876932;760.8787524302393;671.2907579865052;669.0718770518221;901.3788876259023;926.077760311429
2020-07-17 09:57:36.119916;578.3978109170034;811.407262562966;822.6244615030105;570.0016494663124;935.0853062150045;689.8800124555897
```

My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, delimiter = ';')
        
        fig = go.Figure()

        for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.iloc[:,0], y=df.iloc[:,i], name=df.columns[i], yaxis='y'+str(i)))
        
        fig.update_layout(
            xaxis=dict(
                domain=[0.3, 0.7]
            ),
            yaxis=dict(
                title="S1",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#1f77b4"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#1f77b4"
                ),
                side="left",
                position=0.10        
            ),
            yaxis2=dict(
                title="S2",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#ff7f0e"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#ff7f0e"
                ),
                anchor="free",
                overlaying="y",
                side="left",
                position=0.20
            ),
            yaxis3=dict(
                title="S3",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#d62728"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#d62728"
                ),
                anchor="x",
                overlaying="y",
                side="left",
                position=0.30
            ),
            yaxis4=dict(
                title="S4",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#6427bd"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#6427bd"
                ),
                anchor="free",
                overlaying="y",
                side="right",
                position=0.70
            ),
            yaxis5=dict(
                title="S5",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#3758bd"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#3758bd"
                ),
                anchor="free",
                overlaying="y",
                side="right",
                position=0.80
            ),
            yaxis6=dict(
                title="S6",
                titlefont=dict(
                    color="#2690bd"
                ),
                tickfont=dict(
                    color="#2690bd"
                ),
                anchor="free",
                overlaying="y",
                side="right",
                position=0.90
            )
        )
        
        fig.update_layout(
            title_text="Stacked y-axes",
            yaxis={'title':'Values [unit]'}, 
            xaxis={'title':'DateTime'},
            height=600, 
            width=1000
        )
        
        plot(fig)
```

This is my result now:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QPLG0gT2SvWd4_0-piGQsdRy_eTACFn1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build all the `yaxis*` arguments inside your for loop. In the example below, I create a dict named `axes`, add each `yaxis*` subdict and later I call `fig.update_layouts(**axes)`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', delimiter = ';')
        
fig = go.Figure()

colors=["#1f77b4","#ff7f0e","#d62728","#6427bd","#3758bd","#2690bd"]

axes = {
    'xaxis': dict(domain=[0.3, 0.7])
}

for i in range(1, len(df.columns)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.iloc[:,0], y=df.iloc[:,i], name=df.columns[i], yaxis='y'+str(i)))
    s = 'yaxis'
    if i > 1:
        s = s + str(i)
    axes[s] = dict(
        title=f"S{i}",
        titlefont=dict(color=colors[i-1]),
        tickfont=dict(color=colors[i-1])
    )
    if i > 1:
        axes[s]['anchor'] = 'free'
        axes[s]['overlaying'] = 'y'
    if i > len(df.columns) / 2:
        axes[s]['side'] = 'right'
        axes[s]['position'] = 0.3 + 0.1*i
    else:
        axes[s]['side'] = 'left'
        axes[s]['position'] = 0.1*i

fig.update_layout(**axes)
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Stacked y-axes",
    yaxis={'title':'Values [unit]'}, 
    xaxis={'title':'DateTime'},
    height=600, 
    width=1000
)
```